# How to pass enum value using RESTlet in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I could create phone call using RESTlet in Netsuite by the following php code when not having status field .

```
$datastring = array(
       'recordtype' => 'phonecall',
       'gu_action' => 'create',
       'title' => 'test',
       'status'=>'_completed'
);
```

when i pass datastring with status, i am getting error like

```
Array
(
    [custom_error] => Array
        (
            [code] => INVALID_KEY_OR_REF
            [message] => Invalid status reference key _completed.
        )

)
```

The RESTlet script available in https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ganeshprabhus/68a9e5b81e53436bb1d684f857a6c31f/raw/67fe03895f1c31d65c1f283dd51584af45d27c59/NS_Script_2016.2004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try using COMPLETE instead of _completed.

Comment: Working fine. COMPLETE and SCHEDULED. Thank You .

Comment: How to know the correct enum values for the field..?